# Get data from azure DB

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin

I'm new to Azure with Xamarin and am trying to make an app.

How do I retrieve the items from the database?

Currently, this code just adds an item to the database.

```cs
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    TodoItem item = new TodoItem { Text = "Awesome item" };
    await MobileService.GetTable<TodoItem>().InsertAsync(item);
}
```

**Edit**

[@Brandon Minnick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5953643/brandon-minnick), here is the error I mentioned in my comment to your answer:

[image]

Comment: there are multiple sample apps and walkthroughs on the Xamarin website that demonstrate how to do this.  Have you read any of them?

Comment: @Jason yes and they don’t seem to help however if you could point me in the direction of one you think that best applies to my case it’d be appreciated

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services-quickstarts/blob/master/client/xamarin.forms/ZUMOAPPNAME/TodoItemManager.cs

Comment: @Jason I've seen this i'm sorry i'm coming from using parse (but it shut down obviously) and so does it really take that much code just for a query because when I put it in it just spits out a ton of errors.

Comment: then post the code you're trying and the specific errors you're getting an we'll help you.  But asking us to write yet another tutorial when hundreds already exist is pointless.  It's much easier to deal with a specific problem.  And most of the queries in the linked sample are just 1-2 lines each.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the `SyncTable`. This ensures that items in your local database are synced with the items in the remote database.

You can retrive all of the items from the database using `await MobileService.GetSyncTable<TodoItem>()`.

```cs
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    TodoItem item = new TodoItem { Text = "Awesome item" };
    await MobileService.GetSyncTable<TodoItem>().InsertAsync(item);

    List<ToDoItem> allItems = await MobileService.GetSyncTable<TodoItem>().ToEnumerableAsync();
}
```

I like to use this generic class to handle all of my Azure queries

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore;

using UITestSampleApp.Shared;

namespace UITestSampleApp
{
    public class AzureService : IDataService
    {
        #region Constant Fields
        readonly Dictionary<Type, bool> _isInitializedDictionary = new Dictionary<Type, bool>();
        readonly Lazy<MobileServiceClient> _mobileServiceClientHolder = new Lazy<MobileServiceClient>(() => new MobileServiceClient(AzureConstants.AzureDataServiceUrl));
        #endregion

        #region Fields
        int _networkIndicatorCount;
        #endregion

        #region Properties
        MobileServiceClient MobileServiceClient => _mobileServiceClientHolder.Value;
        #endregion

        #region Methods
        public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetItemsAsync<T>() where T : EntityData
        {
            await Initialize<T>();

            return await MobileServiceClient.GetSyncTable<T>().ToEnumerableAsync();
        }

        public async Task<T> GetItem<T>(string id) where T : EntityData
        {
            await Initialize<T>();

            return await MobileServiceClient.GetSyncTable<T>().LookupAsync(id);
        }

        public async Task AddItemAsync<T>(T item) where T : EntityData
        {
            await Initialize<T>();

            await MobileServiceClient.GetSyncTable<T>().InsertAsync(item);
        }

        public async Task UpdateItemAsync<T>(T item) where T : EntityData
        {
            await Initialize<T>();

            await MobileServiceClient.GetSyncTable<T>().UpdateAsync(item);
        }

        public async Task RemoveItemAsync<T>(T item) where T : EntityData
        {
            await Initialize<T>();

            await MobileServiceClient.GetSyncTable<T>().DeleteAsync(item);
        }

        public async Task SyncItemsAsync<T>() where T : EntityData
        {
            await Initialize<T>();

            UpdateNetworkActivityIndicatorStatus(true);

            try
            {
                await MobileServiceClient.GetSyncTable<T>().PullAsync($"all{typeof(T).Name}", MobileServiceClient.GetSyncTable<T>().CreateQuery());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Error during Sync occurred: {ex.Message}");
            }
            finally
            {
                UpdateNetworkActivityIndicatorStatus(false);
            }
        }

        async Task Initialize<T>() where T : EntityData
        {
            if (IsDataTypeInitialized<T>())
                return;

            _isInitializedDictionary?.Add(typeof(T), false);

            await ConfigureOnlineOfflineSync<T>();

            _isInitializedDictionary[typeof(T)] = true;
        }

        async Task ConfigureOnlineOfflineSync<T>() where T : EntityData
        {
            var path = Path.Combine(MobileServiceClient.DefaultDatabasePath, "app.db");
            var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore(path);
            store.DefineTable<T>();

            await MobileServiceClient.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store, new SyncHandler());
        }

        bool IsDataTypeInitialized<T>() where T : EntityData
        {
            var isDataTypeInitalized = _isInitializedDictionary?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key.Equals(typeof(T))).Value;
            return isDataTypeInitalized == true;
        }

        void UpdateNetworkActivityIndicatorStatus(bool isActivityIndicatorDisplayed)
        {
            if (isActivityIndicatorDisplayed)
            {
                Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage.IsBusy = true);
                _networkIndicatorCount++;
            }
            else if (--_networkIndicatorCount <= 0)
            {
                Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage.IsBusy = false);
                _networkIndicatorCount = 0;
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

This code is taken from a Xamarin.Forms sample app that uses Azure Mobile Services:
https://github.com/brminnick/UITestSampleApp/blob/master/Src/UITestSampleApp/Services/AzureService.cs

Comment: when I run the line  List<TodoItem> allItems = (System.Collections.Generic.List<ChurchBuilder.TodoItem>)await MobileService.GetTable<TodoItem>().ToEnumerableAsync(); I get an http error.

Comment: I just added a picture of it to my question above

Comment: In the future, please copy/paste the stack trace instead of adding a screenshot. For iOS, make sure to [set the HttpClient to NSUrlSession](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/http-stack/#Selecting_a_HttpClient_Stack), and for Android, [set the HttpClient to AndroidClientHandler and the TLS to TLS 1.2+](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/http-stack/)

Comment: I just did that however the error is still appearing

Comment: Can you copy/paste the stack trace?

Comment: stack trace is empty

Comment: Dang, it's hard for me to debug the problem without a stack trace. Maybe check that the Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore NuGet package is installed in the Android + iOS projects

Comment: Yep, it's installed.

Comment: Didn't help though

Comment: Bummer! If you can share the source code, or create a reproduction sample, I can take a look!

Comment: One more thought: make sure the Azure URL is `https`, not `http`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161746/discussion-between-apple-geek-and-brandon-minnick).